# I'm unable to add user in Azure Devops Organization

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm a user of a Azure DevOps organization with Basic access along with Project Access Administrator group membership

But when I try to add a user at organization level it gives me a error

> You are a Guest in the connected Azure AD and Guests may not be able
>   to search users in the the Azure AD. Please contact your Azure AD
>   admin to make you a member of the connected Azure AD to enable
>   searching for users.

Could someone please help me on this?

I'm a AAD member and also the user whom I'm trying to add is also AAD Member not sure why it is telling that I'm a guest user.

Comment: For this problem, we need to query your private information for further investigation, you can submit a ticket on our [Develop Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21) site.After that, our engineer need you to provide some private information: organization name, your account, the account you need to invite. Note: choose Viewable by Microsoft Only. After the ticket is created, you can share the link here.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?